# Javafx rotating a group with PersepectiveCamera as child rotates camera about its own axes, and not the group node's

Tags: camera, rotation, transform, perspectivecamera, javafx-3d

Here is my code for my Group which has 3d rotates on it:
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;

```
public class Camera3D extends Group {
    ControllableCamera camera;

    Rotate rx = new Rotate(0, Rotate.X_AXIS);
    Rotate ry = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    Rotate rz = new Rotate(0, Rotate.Z_AXIS);

    public Camera3D() {
        camera = new ControllableCamera(rx, ry, rz);
        getChildren().add(camera);
   }

 }
```

I have three sliders adjusting the angle property of rx, ry, and rz. However, they are rotating it using the camera's axes (i.e. rz is always about the axis going through the screen)

I do not want this. I want these rotations to act on the Camera3D instance instead. Maybe I am just misunderstanding how this part of javafx works, but any help would be appreciated!